# Sign in front of normal vector when calculating surface integral

Tags: integration

My question consideres surface integrals, and calculating them.
The example is:$$\int_Sx^2dydz+y^2dzdx+z^2dxdy$$ where $S$ is outer part of plane $x+y+z=1$ $x,y,z\ge 0$.
So, I know we have to do scalar product between normal vector and $(x^2,y^2,z^2)$. Normal vector should be $\frac{(1,1,1)}{\sqrt{3}}$. I only have doubt whether is it minus or plus in front of fraction. It probably has to do something with part that it is outer part of the plane. But I am not sure how to look at that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are correct to be unsure. The question is unclear because a surface that is closed does not have an "outside" or an "inside"

Comment: Yes it is positive orientation. Also it is not necessary to divide by $\sqrt3$ and get the unit normal. It does cancel out later on.

Comment: So it is plus? But if we had for example outer part of cone than it would be minus. I am not really sure how know that.

Comment: As Ninad said, the question should have written it more clearly. Hence your confusion.

Comment: Whether this surface or say a cone, the question could have written _outward normal_ or _positively oriented_ . That would be the right way.

Comment: And if it was said it is oriented clockwise from positive part of z axis than it would be minus right?

Comment: But here we are talking about a surface and not a curve. So positively oriented means outward normal vector.

Comment: Woops there is a critical typo in my comment, it should say "not closed"